# R openxlsx issue with multiple conditions and conditionalFormatting

Tags: r, excel

I can't get multiple conditionalFormatting instances being respected in the final output (Excel 2007 on Windows 7 currently being used).

Sample code:

```
library("openxlsx")    
rm(list = ls())

set.seed(123)
test <- data.frame("tag" = letters, "nums" = runif(26, -20, 20))

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "Sheet", gridLines = TRUE)

negStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#9C0006", bgFill = "#FFC7CE")
posStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#006100", bgFill = "#C6EFCE")
ExtraNegStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#FFF0F5", bgFill = "#FF0000")
ExtraPosStyle <- createStyle(fontColour = "#98FB98", bgFill = "#228B22")

Heading <- createStyle(textDecoration = "bold", border = "Bottom")

writeData(wb, "Sheet", test)

conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet", cols = 2,
                      rows = 2:27, rule = "< -10", style = negStyle,
                      type = "expression")
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet", cols = 2,
                      rows = 2:27, rule = "> 10", style = posStyle,
                      type = "expression")
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet", cols = 2,
                      rows = 2:27, rule = "< -15", style = ExtraNegStyle,
                      type = "expression")
conditionalFormatting(wb, "Sheet", cols = 2,
                      rows = 2:27, rule = "> 15", style = ExtraPosStyle,
                      type = "expression")

addStyle(wb, "Sheet", cols = 1:2, rows = 1, style = Heading)

saveWorkbook(wb, file = "test.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

If I open the resulting spreadsheet I see this:

[image]

Row 7, 16 and 19 (tag f, o and r) are not formatted as they should be: I would expect bright red and white font.
This is effectively what I achieve if in Excel I go into Conditional Formatting > manage rules and just move the formatting rules this way.

[image]

I obviously tried to move the conditionalFormatting statements in the R code up & down but that doesn't appear to do the trick.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you ever receive a response to this question? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: I am afraid not. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating to the latest (developer) version of openxlsx. I had the same issue as you and at some point after updating I was able to use multiple rules at the same time. I'm not sure what fixed it, but please let me know if that works. This is the code to install the latest dev version as posted on [the author's github page](https://github.com/awalker89/openxlsx). My rules are somewhat more complex than yours, where I am formatting a set of columns based on two different **other** sets of columns, so I can only imagine your example should work!

```
install.packages(c("Rcpp", "devtools"), dependencies=TRUE)
require(devtools)
install_github("awalker89/openxlsx")
```

And of course, don't forget to restart R/RStudio.